# How to insert/update postgresql table using WHERE clause?

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, psycopg2, upsert

I'm using pscopg2 module to write into my database (postgresql). I'm trying to insert or update a column/row value based on an equivalence statement such as:

`INSERT x INTO TABLE A WHERE variable_x MATCHES/EQUAL TO value y IN SAME TABLE;`

Code:

```
def update_existing_record(dev_eui, device_serial_num):

cur = con.cursor()
con.autocommit = True
sql_command = " IF EXISTS (dev_eui == %s) SET severn_db.device_serial_num VALUES (%s)"
#sql_command = "INSERT INTO severn_db (device_serial_num) WHERE EXISTS (dev_eui == dev_eui) VALUES (%s) "
sql_values = (dev_eui, device_serial_num)
cur.execute(sql_command, sql_values,)
cur.close()
```

All I am trying to do is insert or update table column that matches the condition x == y (where x would be a parameter passed in as a local variable to the python function).

Any help?

Comment: `insert into .. on conflict do update`

Comment: I need the full postgresql command as I'm not familiar with the language.

Comment: Then become familiar [Insert](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html), in particular [On Conflict](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT).  FYI,  this `dev_eui == %s` shoul be `dev_eui = %s`, same for `dev_eui == dev_eui`. You are working in SQL not Python.

Comment: The full command is [documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html) and there are [many examples here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+upsert)